# Drawing multiple lines (minimum 9x9) in JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Ok, so now it displays. The Panel is covered up by the lines I have drawn, and I am currently working on figuring out what layout to use. BorderLayout doesn't seem to work the way I want it, but there are many others to try. Thank you for the help, and if you have any other advice, I would love to hear it.

Another addition before I log of for the night: I have settled on the GridLayout, because I can control the size of all the components and then size the frame to fit them all. Now I am working on the inputs. How do I get the information from the TextFields in the JPanel into the JComponent to use as data? The problem arises in the paintComponent method of the JComponent class near the bottom. I will use this solution to help with the networking part of the project.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class GoBoard extends JFrame
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Graphics g;
      JFrame goframe=new JFrame("Go");
      goframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      goframe.setSize(600,700);
      goframe.setLayout(new GridLayout());
      JPanel panel=new JPanel();
      JComponent component=new gocomponent();
      panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      JButton passbutton=new JButton("Pass");
      JButton sendbutton=new JButton("Send");
      JLabel label=new JLabel("Enter the coordinates of the intesection you want to play on.");
      JLabel label2=new JLabel("Click send, Or click pass");
      JLabel blank=new JLabel("        ");
      JLabel blank2=new JLabel("        ");
      JTextField text1=new JTextField(10);
      JTextField text2=new JTextField(10);
      panel.add(label);
      panel.add(label2);
      panel.add(blank);
      panel.add(blank2);
      panel.add(passbutton);
      panel.add(sendbutton);
      panel.add(text1);
      panel.add(text2);
      component.setOpaque(false);
      component.setSize(450,450);
      component.setVisible(true);
      goframe.add(component);
      goframe.add(panel);
      goframe.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class gocomponent extends JComponent
{
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
     for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
     {
         drawhorizontal(g2, 0, i*50, 450, i*50);
         drawvertical(g2, i*50, 0, i*50, 450);
     }
     drawpiece(g2, text1.getText(), text2.getText(), true);
   }
   public void drawhorizontal(Graphics2D g2, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
   {
      g2.setColor(Color.black);
      g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
   }
   public void drawvertical(Graphics2D g2, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
   {
      g2.setColor(Color.black);
      g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
   }
   public void drawpiece(Graphics2D g2, int x, int y, boolean player)
   {
      if(player==true)
      {
         g2.setColor(Color.black);
      }
      if(player==false)
      {
         g2.setColor(Color.white);
      }
      g2.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
   }
}
```

Comment: As the close reason says, this question is a bit too broad; What you will want to do is attempt to solve this yourself first, and if you encounter a problem with your implementation, or have a specific question, go ahead and post (or update this question). You should also be specific about what you don't know, rather than the general (and off topic) "how do I do this" type of question.

Comment: Also, you probably want to draw on a `JPanel`, rather than directly on a `JFrame`.

Comment: within the draw method or in the main?

Comment: I need to make the main method call the component class and activate the paintComponent method to draw the board. I will most likely use the component class to run the connection to the server and handle the game itself, but I need to display first.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify your code just to get it to compile.  I made several changes to give you a starting point for your continued development.

Here's what my version of the Go Frame looks like.

[image]

So, here are the changes I made.

First, you **must always** start a Swing application with a call to SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GoBoard());
}
```

Second, I separated the building of the JFrame and the JPanels into separate methods / classes.  This allows you to focus on one part of the GUI at a time.

Here's the code for the JFrame.

```
public void run() {
    JFrame goframe = new JFrame("Go");
    goframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.add(new GoPanel());
    mainPanel.add(createButtonPanel());

    goframe.add(mainPanel);

    goframe.pack();
    goframe.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    goframe.setVisible(true);
}
```

Here's the code for the button JPanel.  I used a GridBagLayout to get the text fields and the buttons to line up better.

```
private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    int gridy = 0;

    JLabel label = new JLabel(
            "Enter the coordinates of the intesection you want to play on.");
    addComponent(panel, label, 0, gridy++, 2, 1,
            normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Click send, Or click pass");
    addComponent(panel, label2, 0, gridy++, 2, 1,
            normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    text1 = new JTextField(10);
    addComponent(panel, text1, 0, gridy, 1, 1,
            normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    text2 = new JTextField(10);
    addComponent(panel, text2, 1, gridy++, 1, 1,
            normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    JButton passbutton = new JButton("Pass");
    addComponent(panel, passbutton, 0, gridy, 1, 1,
            normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    JButton sendbutton = new JButton("Send");
    addComponent(panel, sendbutton, 1, gridy++, 1, 1,
            normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    return panel;
}

private void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
        int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, 
        Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
            gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, 
            insets, 0, 0);
    container.add(component, gbc);
}
```

And finally, here's the class for the Go board.  You're going to have to put some space around the outside so a full stone will draw on the 1, 1 point.

I pretty much left your code as it was, except you can't draw a stone until after someone has entered stone coordinates.

```
public class GoPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5957209004151437002L;

    public GoPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(451, 451));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            drawhorizontal(g2, 0, i * 50, 450, i * 50);
            drawvertical(g2, i * 50, 0, i * 50, 450);
        }
        String a = text1.getText();
        String b = text2.getText();

        if (a.equals("") || b.equals("")) {

        } else {
            int x = Integer.valueOf(text1.getText());
            int y = Integer.valueOf(text2.getText());
            drawpiece(g2, x, y, true);
        }
    }

    public void drawhorizontal(Graphics2D g2, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    public void drawvertical(Graphics2D g2, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    public void drawpiece(Graphics2D g2, int x, int y, boolean player) {
        if (player == true) {
            g2.setColor(Color.black);
        }
        if (player == false) {
            g2.setColor(Color.white);
        }
        g2.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the whole runnable code.  I put the classes inside the GoBoard class to make it easier to paste.  You should put each class in a separate file.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GoBoard implements Runnable {

    private static final Insets normalInsets = 
            new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);

    private JTextField text1;
    private JTextField text2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GoBoard());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame goframe = new JFrame("Go");
        goframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(new GoPanel());
        mainPanel.add(createButtonPanel());

        goframe.add(mainPanel);

        goframe.pack();
        goframe.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        goframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        int gridy = 0;

        JLabel label = new JLabel(
                "Enter the coordinates of the intesection you want to play on.");
        addComponent(panel, label, 0, gridy++, 2, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Click send, Or click pass");
        addComponent(panel, label2, 0, gridy++, 2, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        text1 = new JTextField(10);
        addComponent(panel, text1, 0, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        text2 = new JTextField(10);
        addComponent(panel, text2, 1, gridy++, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JButton passbutton = new JButton("Pass");
        addComponent(panel, passbutton, 0, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JButton sendbutton = new JButton("Send");
        addComponent(panel, sendbutton, 1, gridy++, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        return panel;
    }

    private void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
            int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, 
            Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
                gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, 
                insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

    public class GoPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5957209004151437002L;

        public GoPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(451, 451));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                drawhorizontal(g2, 0, i * 50, 450, i * 50);
                drawvertical(g2, i * 50, 0, i * 50, 450);
            }
            String a = text1.getText();
            String b = text2.getText();

            if (a.equals("") || b.equals("")) {

            } else {
                int x = Integer.valueOf(text1.getText());
                int y = Integer.valueOf(text2.getText());
                drawpiece(g2, x, y, true);
            }
        }

        public void drawhorizontal(Graphics2D g2, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            g2.setColor(Color.black);
            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }

        public void drawvertical(Graphics2D g2, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            g2.setColor(Color.black);
            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }

        public void drawpiece(Graphics2D g2, int x, int y, boolean player) {
            if (player == true) {
                g2.setColor(Color.black);
            }
            if (player == false) {
                g2.setColor(Color.white);
            }
            g2.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks amazing, like something it would take me months to even think of. Thank you for the help. I will try some of this out tomorrow when I get to class. I have no idea why you would have to change it so much to compile though. And most of this looks like higher level code that is ridiculously outside the curriculum for a 200 level AS degree class. Thank you again.